# Как получить id строки по значению одной из колонок в sqlite на android

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite

Как сделать то, что написано в заголовке?

```
public int getIdRow(String name){
    Cursor cursor = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +DB_TABLE+ " WHERE name = ?"+name,null);
    int id=-1;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        id = cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
        id = cursor.getInt(id);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return id;
}
```

Скажите, что неправильно и как исправить, пожалуйста. Если нужен еще код, то пишите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
Cursor cursor = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +DB_TABLE+ " WHERE name = ?"+name,null);
```

на

```
Cursor cursor = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +DB_TABLE+ " WHERE name = ?", new String[] {name});
```

Comment: А не подскажите, как отправлять уведомления на телефон??